# Installing incompatible ROMS

Tags: rom

I was wondering if you are able to install ROMS, for example, the Ubuntu Touch OS for the GS2 i9100 onto the GS2 SPH-D710. Will it brick my phone?

Comment: If installing incompatible ROMS wont' soft/brick your phone then what would?

Comment: Magic would....

Comment: Do you know any? I'm very jealous of S4 that I see around me.

Comment: Any good ROMS? Not at the moment.

Comment: No Magic that would soft/brick the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no, it is not possible to flash ROMs made for a different model.

Specific to your device, no.  Flashing ROMs for the I9100, I9105, I9100G, I777, and T989 on you device will result in you having a phone-shaped paperweight.

You can find appropriate ROMs for your device [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1707), among other places.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't want to install Ubuntu on my Epic 4G Touch and have it bricked.

Answer (score -1):

WARNING   THIS WILL COMPLETELY UNROOT YOUR DEVICE AND YOU WONT HAVE WIFI
BUT IF YOURE USING DATA, YOUR FINE
BUT YOU SHOULD KNOW HOW TO FLASH STOCK BACK ONTO IT IF SOMETHING GOES WRONG.

Yes you can actually all you do is extract everything from the flashable rom, then go to META-INF/com/google/android/updater.script.
Open it with any text editor. Go to any of the lines that say something like this: (getprop("ro.build.product") == "i9100). Then change the model number already on the line to SPH-D710. now, go and recompile the rom. Then reboot to recovery and install.
                         WARNING

Since you are using an SPH-D710, The wifi might not work, I realized that after installing cyanogenmod 12 lollipop and tried cyanogenmod 13 also and wifi didnt work on either and only the search button and back buttons work. I dont know if the rom youre trying to install has options in settings to edit what your buttons do, but cyanogenmod did. So if youre going to try it with cyanogenmod then just do all the instructions the same.

And please tell me the results If you plan on doing it so I can add that to my list of compatible roms. Thanks.